# Is deleting answers you feel are not good answers a suspension-worthy action?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

The mods at English Usage are intent on undeleting bad answers, even though I've retracted them. In trying to prune, they give suspensions. What are the rules on that? It's literally only a handful of answers, and of course the accepted answers remain untouched.

Comment: It may have looked like a rage quit. Some people try to delete everything they can when they leave. Were they upvoted answers? Any of them the sole answer of the question? These can add to the suspicious look.

Comment: Sounds more directed at English Usage [meta site](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) than here. I don't think there's a network wide policy about this and each site has its own appreciation for this.

Comment: @RetractedAndRetired maybe your evaluation of "not good" answer is a bit harsh and as Patrick says in his answer it has triggered an automatic alert. I'm not a English usage mod so I can't tell for them.

Comment: They should have sent a mod message detailing why they suspended you, in which case you could explain what you were doing (as you did here) after which a resolution should have been agreed to.  Did any of that happen?

Comment: Vandalism is _"action involving deliberate destruction of or damage to public or private property."_ Deletion is destructive, since the work is no longer in the sight of the public. Like we've said, it sounds like it looked like a rage quit, like you were trying to "take your ball and go home" because you were removing your contributions. It's just a misunderstanding. The mods are there to help keep the site clean and under control. Someone destroying an odd amount of content needs to be stopped immediately, and the reasoning can be worked out while the user cannot be destructive.

Comment: Honestly, without (one of) the mod(s) involved chiming in, everything we're saying here is our best guesses. There may have been something more extreme involved. (As in, something that seriously concerned the mods but to you or me would look completely benign.)

Comment: @RetractedAndRetired there is a contact us link in the footer of every site ...

Comment: You will get a mod message in inbox, to which you can reply. Check your inbox. Without a message, they can't suspend you

Comment: Not only email. Check your SE inbox notifications. You will see something like Moderator Message

Answer (score 7):

Speaking as a moderator on another site, what probably happened was that you recently deleted a number of posts and that triggered an automatic flag. We see these as "possible vandalism: deletions (auto)" flags with a list of recently deleted posts.

If they reviewed the posts and found that they contained content worth saving, the moderators might have undeleted those posts and provided our standard warning about a potential rage-quit in action. That moderator message template reads like the following:

> Hello,
>
> I'm writing in reference to your [site] account:
>
> [account]
>
> You have recently removed or defaced a lot of content from your posts.
>   Please note that once you post a question or answer to this site,
>   those posts become part of the collective efforts of others who have
>   also contributed to that content. Posts that are potentially useful to
>   others should not be removed except under extraordinary circumstances.
>   Even if the post is no longer useful to the original author, that
>   information is still beneficial to others who may run into similar
>   problems in the future - this is the underlying philosophy of Stack
>   Exchange.
>
> Extensive deletions take a lot of effort to repair. I have placed your
>   account on hold for 1 day while I reach out to
>   you to avoid any further misunderstandings. Once this matter has been
>   resolved, your reputation score will be restored and your account will
>   resume as normal.
>
> Please respond to this message. I sincerely hope this is just a
>   misunderstanding, but if you feel you have an exceptional reason to
>   remove this content then let me know. If you'd prefer, you can contact
>   Stack Exchange directly through the 'contact us' link at the bottom of
>   the site.
>
> Regards,   [site] Moderation Team

By default, the system triggers a one-day suspension to go along with this message. The purpose of that is to prevent any further deletions and give you a chance to respond. We quickly lift these suspensions if someone provides a good reason why this wasn't a rage-quit, a student trying to hide all their homework at the end of a term, or some other kind of vandalism.

If you respond to that message using your on-site account, and explain what's going on, the moderators will see that response and can lift your suspension. Additionally, as suggested in the message, you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page on the site to get a hold of SE employees. They might not be able to respond as quickly as per-site moderators, due to having to develop for and oversee all of these sites.

Answer (score 4):

> Is deleting answers you feel are not good answers a suspension-worthy action?

Generally not. Sometimes an answer you gave wasn't that good in retrospect. It is fine to delete an answer if you think it should be deleted.

So what happened really? I guess it was something in the line of this: you deleted quite some answers. Your behavior triggered the rage quit warning in a moderator dashboard. The moderator suspended you to prevent more damage to the site.

If the moderator didn't immediately suspend you and just undeleted those answers, and you wanted to override that by deleting the posts again, that would definitely qualify as a reason to suspend.

What you should have done in such a case: ask on the site's meta what to do. Discuss what you want to do and wait on consensus. Or contact the team by using the Contact Us page.

Comment: I don't think they can post on their site meta when suspended.

Comment: I know. He should have before he got suspended and the moderator undeleted posts.

Comment: You have just a few posts there. If you delete more than a few, it will trigger automatic scripts. What should the moderator do then? Wait until you were finished 'deleting everything' and ask then? Not saying that was your intention, but the moderator can't know. They have to act now! That is why you were suspended. You can contact the moderator from the email message you received.